# How to completely uninstall brew and re-install brew in ubuntu 19.04

Tags: react-native, homebrew, linuxbrew

I installed homebrew on ubuntu 19.04 and it's accidentally stop, so the install not complete. but the folder already created.

If I install it again

```
sudo apt install linuxbrew-wrapper
```

I get a message:

> linuxbrew-wrapper is already the newest version

but if I write command :

```
brew upgrade
```

I get this message:

> Command 'brew' not found, but can be installed with:
>
> sudo apt install linuxbrew-wrapper".

Can anyone help me fix this?

Answer (score 49):

Maybe this can help more people...

I just executed the following command line

```
$/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall.sh)"
```

This is the same url as in here [Homebrew homepage](https://github.com/homebrew/install#uninstall-homebrew) but instead of ***install.sh***, I used ***uninstall.sh***.

[image: homebrew uninstall]

Comment: Beside the `rm` from other answers, is [also necessary to remove it](https://askubuntu.com/a/1499535/349837) from `.profile`.

Answer (score 15):

After performing what https://stackoverflow.com/a/57208010/2787992 said, you might need to run

```
sudo rm -rf /home/linuxbrew
```

Answer (score 12):

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/uninstall.sh)"

sudo rm -rf /home/linuxbrew
```

For details see: https://www.how2shout.com/linux/how-to-install-brew-ubuntu-20-04-lts-linux/

Answer (score 4):

Source your bashrc first

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 4):

Try uninstalling the packages.

To remove just linuxbrew-wrapper package

```
sudo apt-get remove linuxbrew-wrapper
```

If you want to delete configuration and data files

```
sudo apt-get purge linuxbrew-wrapper
```

Comment: thanks man, after i install it again, it say "E: Linuxbrew directory detected, but it seems broken. Try to remove '/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew' and install again."

Comment: @walidthalib was this commands executed ? Did you able to install it again after deleting the directory ?

Comment: yes, i executed. But the directory still exist in home/linuxbrew/ . So if i install it again it's not complete.

Comment: Note:  linuxbrew-wrapper appears to no longer be relevant in 2023. I recommend using the official Linuxbrew instructions