# linuxbrew/lib/ld.so: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory

Tags: bash, linuxbrew

I am having a problem about linuxbrew.

```
bash: /lustre7/home/lustre4/user1/applications/bin/cut: /lustre7/home/lustre4/user1/.linuxbrew/lib/ld.so: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I tried to uninstall linuxbrew using instructions at its website, but somehow it didn't work (because of sudo requirements).

there is linuxbrew directory but I can't remove when I type `rm -r linuxbrew`  it says;

```
-bash: /lustre7/home/lustre4/user1/applications/bin/rm: /lustre7/home/lustre4/user1/.linuxbrew/lib/ld.so: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory
```

When I tried to install homebrew it says your CPU is not supported. (I tried this before and it worked, but now it is not working.)

I want to solve this problem but I couldn't find any solution. I am not able to run sudo and yum commands because I am not root. I am a user at a linux cluster.

Answer (score 0):

OK. I finally was able to solve this issue.

I am wring in case someone else may have the same issue.

First, this was related to a bash problem. I recently installed a tool that put some variables to both bashrc and bash_profile and altered path of bin directory. 
I wasn't able to use system commands such as rm, ls, cat etc. and I wasn't able to run system ruby. Paths of all commands and ruby were in my bin directory under my application directory.

What I did is;
I edited my bash_profile by cancelling the new path that caused conflict between bash_profile and bashrc. This enabled me run system commands.

I uninstalled linuxbrew as described in its website.

I removed linuxbrew from my home directory, and cancelled its path in bash_profile (comment out).

I installed homebrew again and put its path to my bashrc.

Now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

I could uninstall linuxbrew using the procedure I described in here:

[How to completely uninstall brew and re-install brew in ubuntu 19.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57207954/how-to-completely-uninstall-brew-and-re-install-brew-in-ubuntu-19-04/64722984#64722984)

-> In short, I just replaced `install.sh` by `uninstall.sh` and it worked...

```
$/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall.sh)"
```